# Как добавить функционал pause/resume/stop приложению на JavaFX?

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, spring-boot

Есть десктопное приложение, работающее на `JavaFX` `(OpenJFX)`. Логика написана на связке `Spring Boot + JavaFX` с помощью `FXWeaver`.
Задача заключается в следующем: клиенту нужна возможность ставить приложение на паузу/возобновлять/останавливать (по нажатию соответствующей кнопки на форме). У меня есть мысль запускать сервис в отдельном потоке (унаследовавшись от `Thread`), и добавить такой функционал:

1. Pause: вызывать `super.sleep(1)` в цикле, пока не будет изменём флаг paused
2. Resume: ставить флаг `paused` в `false`
3. Stop: `this.interrupt()`

Не уверен, что это корректный подход к решению такой задачи, потому и пишу сюда. Можете дать парочку подсказок, как сделать правильно?

Comment: В класс добавить 2 поля: `stopped` и `paused`. В методе `run` сделать `while`, который в условии будет делать проверку на: `!stopped`. Внутри этого `while`-а сделать еще один `while`, в условии которого будет `paused`. И если поток будет на паузе то будет выполнятся вложенный `while`, до тех пор пока пауза не будет убрана. `this.interrupt()` - не гарантирует остановку потока. Поток можно остановить когда заканчивается выполнение метода `run`, что мы и сделаем первым `while`-ом. `super.sleep(1)` - тут есть четкое время и поэтому для паузы не особо подходит.

Comment: Есть вариант использования методов `wait` и `notify`, но он более сложен, но в то же время более красив.

Comment: + ко всему учтите что после остановки потока сервиса при старте его же нужно будет опять создать поток и запустить.

Comment: Можно пример с wait и notify?

Comment: Я вижу это так: Есть класс который отвечает за управление потоком. Пускай это будет `ServiceControl`. Это не поток, а обычный класс (возможно бин, если спринг используется). У него есть те же два поля `stopped` и `paused`. Так же у него есть методы управления: `start`, `stop`, `pause`, `resume`. Эти методы изменяют значение полей, при этом когда меняется любое поле в классе нужно вызвать метод `notifyAll`. Далее. Есть метод `isPaused` - он должен быть синхронизирован и в нем идет проверка на паузу. Если истина вызывается метод `wait` и поток засыпает в ожидании.

Comment: Когда вызывают метод `resume`, поле `paused` меняется и вызывается метод `notifyAll`, тем самым оповещая поток что можно продолжать работу и поток работает. В методе `isPaused` находится `while`, который проверяет поле.

Comment: использование `sleep` позволяет не делать работу, но всё равно потребляет CPU (== батарейку)

Answer (score 0):

wait/notify

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class MyTask {

    public static enum State {Initial, Running, Paused, Stopped};

    private final Thread worker = new Thread(this::workLoop);
    private final Object stateLock = new Object();
    private State state = State.Initial;

    private void writeState(EnumSet<State> expectedStates, State newState, Runnable onChange) {
        synchronized (stateLock) {
            if (expectedStates.contains(state)) {
                state = newState;
                onChange.run();
            }
        }
    }

    private State readState() {
        synchronized (stateLock) {
            if (state == State.Paused) {
                try {
                    stateLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // nothing to do
                }
            }
            return state;
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        writeState(EnumSet.of(State.Initial), State.Running, worker::start);
    }

    public void stop() {
        writeState(EnumSet.of(State.Running, State.Paused), State.Stopped, stateLock::notifyAll);
    }

    public void pause() {
        writeState(EnumSet.of(State.Running), State.Paused, stateLock::notifyAll);
    }

    public void resume() {
        writeState(EnumSet.of(State.Paused), State.Running, stateLock::notifyAll);
    }

    private void workLoop() {
        while (readState() != State.Stopped) {
            nextIteration();
        }
    }

    private void nextIteration() {
        // do some small work here and let loop to verify its state
    }
}
```